# How to config tomcat in intellij

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I config tomcat7 in intellij, some error happens.

it prompt " Invalid Data: port is not specified" The port I set is 8081

how to solve the problem? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Run/Debug Configurations" then select  "Startup/Connection" Tab -> click "Debug" option and change port number from zero to another.

Comment: I have numbers specified for all ports and it's still complaining

Comment: I had to recreate my tomcat instance in intellij. Looks like updating from intellij 2014 upward breaks old tomcat configs.